# I am getting error91 " Object variable or with block not set " while selecting the range for creating pivot table purpose

Tags: vba, excel

```
SrcData1 = "[" & firstreport.name & "]" & Reportsheet.name & "!" & Range("A1:AR" & reportICX).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Comment: are first report and reportsheet set?

Comment: yes, they both are declared as public variables and set in another module . Creating a separate module for pivots

Comment: @jaya you can try a slightly different approach setting the Pivot Table's range (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I offer another approach, I am not a big fan of setting ranges with long strings inside the brackets, Why not use the **Range** and **Sheets** objects with their full capabilities ?

I assume, in your other module you decalred the following objects (and set them correctly):

1. `firstreport as Workbook`
2. `Reportsheet as Worksheet` - as a sheet in **firstreport** Workbook.
3. `reportICX as Long` - representing a lastrow (or something similar) in ***Reportsheet*** Sheet.

Then, you can set the PivotTable Range like this:

```
Set SrcData1 = Reportsheet.Range("A1:AR" & reportICX)
```

It works nicely in all of my dynamic coded Pivot Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the following on the line before and tell what you get:

```
debug.print firstreport.name
debug.print Reportsheet.name
debug.print reportICX
```

SrcData1 = "[" & firstreport.name & "]" & Reportsheet.name & "!" & Range("A1:AR" & reportICX).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

What type of data is SrcData1?

Answer (score 0):

Either `firstreportor` or `Reportsheet` is not set.

Insert this two lines before the the error message; then check the immediate window to see hcih one isn't set.

```
Debug.Print "firstreport:", firstreport Is Nothing

Debug.Print "Reportsheet:", Reportsheet Is Nothing
```

[image]